# rlwrap cannot read/write its own history

Tags: ubuntu, rlwrap

I created a simple script like the following called "/usr/bin/mytool1" and make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/rlwrap /usr/bin/perl

while (1) {
    chomp($cmd = <STDIN>);
    print "cmd=$cmd\n";
}
```

The problem is, if I run it as a regular user, it works fine.

Then I did a "sudo bash" and as root, I run mytool1,  it works fine too.

Now I am back as a regular user,  running command "mytool1" will give error like:

```
rlwrap: cannot read and write /home/user1/.perl_history: Permission denied
```

I did some investigation, here is what I found:

```
$ ls -l /home/user1/.perl_history
-rw------- 1 root root 138 Dec  6 18:13 /home/user1/.perl_history
```

The problem here is, `rlwrap` will change the owner of `/home/user1/.perl_history` to root when it runs as root.

I think this is a bug on rlwrap because in the case Ubuntu,  `$HOME` didn't change after I run `sudo bash`,  `rlwrap` should have used `$USER` to construct the history file.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to modify and recompile `rlwrap`, just specify the history file on the command line:

```
rlwrap --history-filename=$HOME/.${USER}_command_history command
```

I am surprised that Ubuntu's `sudo` preserves `$HOME` by default, I cannot see why this would ever be useful (there are [occasional murmurings](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1373495) against this policy on the Ubuntu lists, but certainly no storms of protest)

In the meantime, I will keep `rlwrap`s behaviour as it is, but [try to find out](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/39) whether and how other programs avoid problems like this ([not all of them do](https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/ubuntu-nano-error-reading-home-nano_history-permission-denied/))

Edit (aug 2019): From `sudo - 1.8.27-1ubuntu2` onwards Ubuntu (finally!) [restores](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/429518784/sudo_1.8.27-1ubuntu2_source.changes) `sudo` handling of `$HOME` to what everyone else does : it will *not* preserve `$HOME` by default. This means that `rlwrap` will be able to read and write its own history when running under `sudo`, even without the extra `--history-filename` argument.

Hans (`rlwrap` maintainer)

Comment: Thanks @hans-lub, your solution is the best!   By the way I guess you meant to say `rlwrap --history-filename=$HOME/.${USER}_command_history command`.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` might be configured with security policy not to change environment variables, including `HOME`. You can try to override this behaviour with `-H` option. See `man sudo` for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey for the suggestion.  I have other tools that may be broken if I do that. Would rather do something to rlwrap.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works for me:  Download the rlwrap [source](http://freecode.com/projects/rlwrap) and make change to src file "main.c" and after line 604, add

```
history_filename = malloc(100);
sprintf(history_filename, "/home/%s/.%s_history",getenv("USER"),  command_name);
```

now rlwrap will use different history file for different users.